# Computer clock cycles

Tags: compiler-construction, clock

Explain how the efficiency of the compiler affects the performance of a computer program? An application written in C takes 30 seconds to run on a computer processor. A new C compiler was installed that generates half the number of instructions when compared to the old compiler. The new compiler, however, increases the average number of cycles per instruction (CPI) by 20%. How fast will the application run using this new compiler?

I have this question but don't understand how to work it out, without getting the instruction count of the old/orignal compiler, any help?

Comment: This looks like a homework problem so I will only provide a hint. Try to write down one formula for the execution time for the old code and one formula for the execution time for the new code and try to express one in terms of the other.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/sauzjf, this is the formula im using for the old compiler, when trying to express one in terms of the other would my final answer appear in algebraic form?

Comment: Use the same formula for the new compiler in combination with the information from question statement. The rest is just algebraic manipulation.